# ColumnFormFormSet objects has no attribute ‘save’

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to create 30 fields in the `design.html`, after I successfully added that using `django formset` When I try to submit the form instead of saving the field to the database, it throws me an error saying `'ColumnFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'save'` how can I solve this problem?

models.py:

```
class Type(models.Model):

    TYPE_OF_DATA = (

        ('Number', 'Number'),

        ('character', 'character'),

        ('check_box', 'check_box'),

        ('date', 'date'),

        ('image', 'image'),

             )

    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices= TYPE_OF_DATA)

class Column(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     selec_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Column

class ColumnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ['name', 'selec_type']
```

views.py:

```
From .forms import ColumnForm
From django.forms import formset_factory

def design(request):
    ColumnFormSet = formset_factory(ColumnForm, extra=30)
    formset = ColumnFormSet
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ColumnFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('Home')
    else:
        formset = ColumnFormSet()
    return render (request, 'design.html', {'formset':formset})
```

template.design.html:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form}}
   {% for form in formset %}
        {{form.as_p}}
   {% endfor %}
<button type='submit'>Save<button/>
<form/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `save()` on a regular `Formset`, you probably want to be using a [`ModelFormset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet) instead.

Replacing the formset_factory import in your views.py with modelformset_factory should do the trick.

```
From .forms import ColumnForm
From django.forms import modelformset_factory

def design(request):
    ColumnFormSet = modelformset_factory(Column, fields = ('name', 'selec_type'), extra=30)
    formset = ColumnFormSet
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ColumnFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('Home')
    else:
        formset = ColumnFormSet()
    return render (request, 'design.html', {'formset':formset})
```

Comment: The error is gone, but it throws another: `'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'private_fields'`

Comment: @Ganyen The new error is most likely a different bug. There's a couple different things that could cause it. Check out these [other SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27ModelFormOptions%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27private_fields%27) with the same error and see if you are having the same issue.